# Which test can be used to diagnose typhoid fever

Tags: human-biology

The only thing I found was the widal test, which is no longer an acceptable clinical method. I can't find much information about this anywhere else other than [the test needs to analyze samples of blood, poo, and pee](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/typhoid-fever/diagnosis/). Is there a specific name for this test?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, it is good to check multiple sources before posting — have you read the [wikipedia article on typhoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoid_fever#Diagnosis)? Thanks! 

Comment: I have voted this question as off-topic for SE Biology as it is merely asking about current clinical practice rather than about the biology underlying a medical condition or test. It might be on-topic on SE Medical Sciences.